# THREE.Js tween animate camera.setLens()

Tags: camera, three.js

I it seem that it is not possible to animate a cameraZoom via. setLens.

I tryed to move the Cam backward and simultanuous Zoom via setLens.

Any Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: do you update the camera projection matrix for every frame during the animation?

Comment: the camera is set to matrixAutoUpdate = true
I tryed camera.updateProjectionMatrix(); in the render loop.
doesnt do anything. I can enter camera.setLens(50); on the console
and its working.

Comment: well, than maybe show your twweening code? :) Maybe something is wrong, there

Answer (score 0):

```
function zoomLens(lens, endLens){
            var tweenLens = new TWEEN.Tween(lens).to(endLens, 2000);
            tweenLens.onUpdate(function(){
                   camera.setLens(lens);
                });
            tweenLens.start();
        }
```

in renderloop :

TWEEN.update();